# Is there a way to widen the click area for ImageButton?

Tags: android, android-button, android-imagebutton

I have a table with each cell having multiple buttons. I'm noticing that since the `ImageButtons` are small, sometimes the user ends up clicking the cell when they really meant to click the `ImageButton`.

Is there a way to widen the clickable area of an `Imagebutton`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TouchDelegate.

Example:

```
 Rect delegateArea = new Rect();

 button.getHitRect(delegateArea);

 delegateArea.top -= 60000;
 delegateArea.bottom += 60000;
 delegateArea.left -= 60000;
 delegateArea.right += 60000;

 final TouchDelegate expandedArea = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea,
                    button);

 if (View.class.isInstance(button.getParent())) {
          ((View) button.getParent()).setTouchDelegate(expandedArea);
 }
```

Hope its help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the padding on the `ImageButton`?  This usually means *make the contents not touch the sides of the view* then just make the view a bit bigger to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to affect the visual bounds, use [a `TouchDelegate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html). This is covered in [the developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate).

Answer (score 0):

Since padding is a space between view's content and its border, padding is your friend. Increase button's padding it and you notice that clickable area became bigger.

Answer (score 0):

set `duplicateParentState` to `ImageButton` , so that when parent area is clicked , the `ImageButton` will receive the click

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```